# Different permissions for similar batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, notepad++

I just started work on two different **Batch** script files (with `.cmd` extension) and they're still one-liners:

```
:: run.cmd
::
:: Batch file for running various processes for 'XXXXXX' project
Rscript.exe --vanilla build/build-report.R
```

and

```
:: update.cmd
::
:: A Batch script for updating the local database in the 'XXXXXX' project.
Rscript.exe --vanilla data/download-data.R
```

They both worked perfectly in Command Prompt and Powershell. However, when I tested them with double-clicking in Windows Explorer GUI, one of them refused and I got a message that it was due to a permissions issue.

I eventually opened the **'Properties'** dialog, and truly the permissions on the problematic file were more restricted; when I adjusted these, the script now ran as expected.

**My question is:** How did this difference in permissions arise? I used the same application (*Notepad++*) to write the files and the workflow for both was practically identical.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you _move_ the file(s) from another folder to the current location? See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310316/how-permissions-are-handled-when-you-copy-and-move-files-and-folders)

Comment: A-ha!. I had initially saved the problematic file as a `.bat` file. I renamed it in Explorer, which is basically `cp`/`mv`... That should be it. Thanks a million.